# check_http plugin failing to check strings separated with multiple spaces in between

Tags: nagios

I have this URL where content strings are separated on the webpage. I need to check where on the same line those two strings are present or not.

Say, on this page I have "API Operational" strings present. I am not sure about how many spaces are present in between these two. Also, this Operation string is "component-status" in span class of that HTML page which I don't know how we can handle from shell.

Comment: It is impossible to help unless you post samples of the string(s).

Comment: Say, on this page I have "API                          Operational" strings present. I am not sure about how many spaces are present in between these two.
Also, this Operation string is "component-status" in span class of that html page which I dunno how we can handle from shell.

Comment: Did the answer below help at all? If so, please consider accepting it with the checkmark; otherwise, let us know what the result was.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [stock check_http plugin](http://nagios-plugins.org/doc/man/check_http.html), then you can use the `-r` (aka `--regex`) flag:

> -r, --regex, --ereg=STRING
>
> Search page for regex STRING

with a regular expression of: `API +Operational`, which matches those characters, with a special meaning in the `+` that says "match one or more spaces". The regular expression matching is case-sensitive by default; see the `-R` flag to make it case-insensitive (or use `[Aa][Pp][Ii]`, for example, to indicate which letter casing is acceptable).

The `-s` string-matching option looks for an exact match of that string, using the [`strstr` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html#tag_16_586)